# Which is the appropriate hook for each tasks in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

Usually we use `init`, `admin_init` to run some process, `admin_print_scripts`, `admin_print_styles` to put `script` and `style` tags in the `head` and `template_redirect` to the same but for the `front-end`, etc. but always seems difficult find the appropriate hook for each tasks. It would be very helpful have a clear guide on this.
Which is the appropriate hook for each tasks in wordpress? I have read that exists over 1000 hooks in wordpress so I ask for general tips of course.  Something to have in account when we face this kind of decisions.

Comment: This is a very abstract question. It all depends on what you want to do - if you want some computation done after user is added to the system - use `add_user_to_blog`, etc.

Comment: http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/actions - here is a list of all hooks, just see what suits you.

Comment: I know is a general question and I said it (I am risking my reputation to serious downvotes). But it is a good question. I always dedicate too much time to decide which `hook` use. That's why I asked for some general tip. Thanks.- :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [Adam Brown's](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook) is the classical resource. The Codex is a collective wiki-effort and has it shortcomings, but there's a [documentation renewal work](http://make.wordpress.org/docs/) going on. [Query Posts](http://queryposts.com/) is a good resource maintained by one of [WordPress Answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) moderators (but the *Hooks* section is not live yet).

What I normally do is to search for the function I'm using inside the core code and look up for useful hooks. For example, the function [`wp_dropdown_categories`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-includes/category-template.php#L299) has 4 available filters.